# Searching multiple databases to output lowest value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT product_name ,MIN(product_price) product_price,link FROM(
select jumia.product_name,jumia.product_price,jumia.product_image,jumia.link from jumia INNER JOIN
jumia ON jumia.id = olx.id 
where product.name like '%{$search}%'
UNION
select olx.product_name,olx.product_price,olx.product_image, olx.link from olx INNER JOIN
olx ON olx.id =  jumia.id
where product.name like '%{$search}%')Minim
GROUP BY product_name,product_image
");
```

I am trying to create a query from two tables with similar column names as displayed above that will allow me to display the rows between the two tables that have the lowest price.

For example, if `product_name` called `mattresses` is searched the matching item in my database whose price is lower between the two table names should be displayed. Some help would be appreciated

Comment: what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the general idea of what you're trying to do:

```
SELECT id, price
FROM (SELECT id, price FROM T1 WHERE price = (SELECT min(price) FROM T1)
      UNION
      SELECT id, price FROM T2 WHERE price = (SELECT min(price) FROM T2)
     ) AS M
ORDER BY price ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up changing the code and removing the ordering at the end and this finally worked. I hadn't properly linked my database using foreign keys, and changed my code to reflect this.

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "
SELECT product_name 
     , MIN(product_price) product_price
     , link 
  FROM
     ( select j.product_name
            , j.product_price
            , j.link 
         from jumia j
         JOIN olx 
           ON j.categoryID = olx.categoryID 
        where j.product_name like '%{$search}%'
        UNION select olx.product_name
                   , olx.product_price
                   , olx.link 
                from olx 
                JOIN jumia 
                  ON jumia.categoryID = olx.categoryID 
               where olx.product_name like '%{$search}%'
     ) x
");
```

Comment: I think the moment' s passed